# JSRender unable to data-link in subtemplate

Tags: jsrender

I am new in using JS-render, I copied the demo code in [JSrender Demo site](https://www.jsviews.com/#samples/jsr/composition/tmpl-objects), and added *input data-link="name"*, but I found the "name" could not shown in the textbox.

Could anyone can help? Many thanks.

Best Rgds

```
<script id="columnTemplate" type="text/x-jsrender">
  <div>
    <em>{{:name}}</em>
    <input data-link="name" />
  </div>
</script>

<script id="rowTemplate" type="text/x-jsrender">
  <span>
    <b>{{:name}}</b>
    <input data-link="name" />
  </span>
</script>


var movies = [
  {
    title: "Meet Joe Black",
    tmpl: "columnTemplate",
    languages: [
      {name: "English"},
      {name: "French"}
    ]
  },
  {
    title: "Eyes Wide Shut",
    tmpl: "rowTemplate",
    languages: [
      {name: "French"},
      {name: "Esperanto"},
      {name: "Spanish"}
    ]
  }
```

Comment: You need to add a assign the template to var myTemplate = $.movies("#columnTemplate"); and then render it var html = myTemplate.render(movies);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are wanting to add dynamic two-way data-binding (data-linking) to a JsRender template. To do that you need to use jsviews.js and not jsrender.js.

Take a look at the introductory [Playing with JsViews](https://www.jsviews.com/#jsvplaying@twoway), and you will see how to convert a JsRender sample to a data-linked (dynamic) JsViews sample. Read up to the [two-way data binding](https://www.jsviews.com/#jsvplaying@twoway) sample, for example.

You JsViews version of the [Composition, using contextual template objects](https://www.jsviews.com/#samples/jsr/composition/tmpl-objects) sample will end with this code:

```
var movieTemplate = $.templates("#movieTemplate");

var nestedTemplates = {
  columnTemplate: $.templates("#columnTemplate"),
  rowTemplate: $.templates("#rowTemplate"),
  conditionalTemplate: $.templates("#conditionalTemplate")
};

movieTemplate.link("#movieList", movies, nestedTemplates);
```

which replaces the following original code from the JsRender (static template rendering) sample:

```
var movieTemplate = $.templates("#movieTemplate");

var nestedTemplates = {
  columnTemplate: $.templates("#columnTemplate"),
  rowTemplate: $.templates("#rowTemplate"),
  conditionalTemplate: $.templates("#conditionalTemplate")
};

var html = movieTemplate.render(movies, nestedTemplates);

$("#movieList").html(html);
```

Also, in the template itself, you need to specify where you want [data-linked tags](https://www.jsviews.com/#linked-tag-syntax). For example, replace `{{>name}}` with `{^{>name}}`.

Comment: It works! Thanks very much.

May I ask another question, I would like to update the template by "$.observable(data).setProperty("tmpl", "#rowTemplate");", but it seems not work, is there anything I missing? thank you.

Comment: You can observably change a template, as in this example: https://www.jsviews.com/#jsvfortag@chgtmpl. But in the case of using contextual parameters, such as ~rowTemplate, in  `{^{if name.charAt(0)==='E' ^tmpl=~rowTemplate}}` it can require more advanced APIs such as view.ctxPrm(...), see https://www.jsviews.com/#jsvviewobject@ctxprm.

Comment: Oh, and could you mark the answer above as "accepted", since it answers your initial question? Thanks...